# How to merge askubuntu.com and stackoverflow.com accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)
>   [How can I link accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/how-can-i-link-accounts)

I notice the StackExchange at the top left!

Is there a way to merge these accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are already 'merged', see your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1350816/alex?tab=accounts). Nothing needs to be done, they're already linked.

If you end up with profiles on two different sites that *aren't* connected via a network profile, see:

[How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)